# jquery pop up on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/nVZEB/6/

a pop up should be displayed on the click of this

testingPopup

but I see this In this issue on page load itself....
how to hide this and it should show in the pop up only

```
$(function() {

var popup = false;

$(".open").click(function(){
    alert(123);
    if(popup === false){
        $("#overlayEffect").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).parent().find('.popupContainer').fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).parent().find('.close').fadeIn("slow");
        center();
        popup = true;
    }    
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        hidePopup();
    });

    $(".overlayEffect").click(function(){
        hidePopup();
    });

function center(){
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $(".popupContainer").height();
    var popupWidth = $(".popupContainer").width();
    $(".popupContainer").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": 85,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });

    }
function hidePopup(){
    if(popup===true){
        $(".overlayEffect").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".popupContainer").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".close").fadeOut("slow");
        popup = false;
    }
}

} ,jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a `hidden` class on the `popupContainer` div, but you don't have any styles for it.

Try adding this to your styles:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```